# Is there a "for" syntax for flatmap?

Tags: scala

Is there a "for" syntax for

```
c flatmap ( x => d flatmap (y => f(x,y) ) )
```

?

Because I've used Haskell in the past, I keep expecting the "for" syntax in Scala to mimic the "do" syntax of Haskell. This is probably an unrealistic expectation. In Haskell which I could write

```
do x <- c
   y <- d
   f(x, y)
```

Comment: A good resource on for comprehensions: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html#translating-for-comprehensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just flatten the result:

```
val c = 1 to 3
val d = 4 to 6
def f(x: Int, y: Int) = Vector(x,y)

c flatMap ( x => d flatMap (y => f(x,y) ) )
// Vector(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6)

(for { x <- c; y <- d } yield f(x,y)).flatten
// Vector(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6)
```

Presumably this is a much less frequently used case since it is necessarily less common that the output of the `for` is flattenable.  And sticking `.flatten` on the end is pretty easy, so having a special syntax for it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: 3 good answers. I'm accepting this one, but Christophe and Peter also have good answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could also map the last result on itself.

Using the same example as dhg:

```
val c = 1 to 3
val d = 4 to 6
def f(x: Int, y: Int) = Vector(x,y)

for { 
  x <- c
  y <- d
  z <- f(x,  y) 
} yield z
// Vector(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6)
```

Which corresponds to:

```
c flatMap ( x => d flatMap (y => f(x,y) map (identity) ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Flattening may impact performance but i think scalac is clever enough to encode

```
for {
  x <- c
  y <- d
  z <- f(x,y)
} yield z
```

into

```
c flatMap { x => d flatMap { y => f(x,y) } }
```

This is annoying that the 'for' syntax is not as convenient as the 'do'-notation (writing `_ <- someExpression` instead of just `someExpression` in a for feels my heart with sadness).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I realize that I've done this myself in the past. When the expression in the `f(x,y)` place is small, it looks good.  Sometimes that expression is a page long, and then it just seems weird (to me, anyway) to have a "for header" that is over a page long.

Comment: "Sometimes that expression is a page long," good grief, why? Time for some helper functions, I feel.

Comment: A big `match` is why. Yes, helper functions help.